# "LateInitializationError: Field '_client@64280004' has not been initialized."

Tags: flutter, dart, agora.io

```
late AgoraClient _client;
```

This is how I initialized the agora Client with a late modifier.

Below is the AgoraVideoViewer

```
children: [
            AgoraVideoViewer(
              client: _client
            ),
            AgoraVideoButtons(
              client: _client
            )
          ],
```

I tried nulling the AgoraClient as shown below

```
AgoraClient? _client;
```

```
children: [
    AgoraVideoViewer(
      client: _client!
    ),
    AgoraVideoButtons(
      client: _client!
    )
],
```

This returned "Null check operator used on a null value" and proceeded to the call screen but displaying a white screen

```
Future<void> _initAgora() async {
await _client.initialize();
String link = "https://agoratokenserver.rich670.repl.co/access_token?channelName=${widget.channelName}";
Response response = await get(Uri.parse(link));
Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);

setState(() async {
  token = data["token"];
});
_client = AgoraClient(
  agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
    appId: "fa3ebd1e9f854c9c8a60430b5fe4d64c",
    tempToken: token,
    channelName: widget.channelName,
  ),
  enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone],
);
Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((value) => setState(() => isLoading = false),);}
```

Take a look at my constructor _initAgora();

Comment: I am using a token server so its impossible to name the token and channel name in an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should try using question mark '?' instead of '!' sign.

Comment: It doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved it

```
late AgoraClient client = AgoraClient(
  agoraConnectionData: AgoraConnectionData(
    appId: "fa3ebd1e9f854c9c8a60430b5fe4d64c",
    tempToken: token,
    channelName: widget.channelName,
  ),
  // agoraChannelData: AgoraChannelData(
  //   channelProfile: ChannelProfile.LiveBroadcasting,
  //   clientRole: ClientRole.Audience,
  // ),
  enabledPermission: [Permission.camera, Permission.microphone],
);
```

I changed initialization of the 'AgoraClient' from the constructor to the initializer.
At first it had an error on 'token' and 'channelName' but then I labelled the AgoraClient as 'late'

Check the block of code above